# Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in default.php on line 37 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in default.php on line 37 File not found

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

Hello iam new to joomla  creating a module mod_testimonial. I this have put the data into `$rows = $db->loadObjectList();` from the helper file,

and the the data in the $rows after echo  is

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => james
            [testimonial] => Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
            [regdate] => 2013-12-31 13:24:29
            [id] => 37
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Tom
            [testimonial] => Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            [regdate] => 2013-12-31 14:45:56
            [id] => 38
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Alyson
            [testimonial] => is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
            [regdate] => 2014-01-03 14:52:09
            [id] => 42
        )

)
```

in my default.php file the i had fetched the data from array as like this.

```
 <p><?php print_r($rows[0]->testimonial);?><span class="testimonial-by"> —<?php print_r($rows[0]->name);?>,<?php echo date('M Y',strtotime($rows[1]->regdate)); ?>,</span></p>



  <p><?php print_r($rows[1]->testimonial);?><span class="testimonial-by">—<?php print_r($rows[1]->name);?>,<?php echo date('M Y',strtotime($rows[2]->regdate)); ?>,</span></p>



<p><?php print_r($rows[2]->testimonial);?><span class="testimonial-by">—<?php print_r($rows[2]->name);?>,<?php echo date('M Y',strtotime($rows[0]->regdate)); ?>,</span></p>
```

my helper file is

```
static function getRecord($params)
    {

        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        $query = "SELECT name,testimonial,regdate,id FROM #__testimonial WHERE published = '1' AND featured='1' ";
        $db->setQuery( $query);
        $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
        return $rows;
    }
```

.Till here its all okk but if i will unpublish or unfeatured the  data from the back end it will raise an error like this

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in modules\mod_testimonial\tmpl\default.php on line 37

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in modules\mod_testimonial\tmpl\default.php on line 37
File not found
```

i know this is because there is no

```
offset [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Alyson
            [testimonial] => is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
            [regdate] => 2014-01-03 14:52:09
            [id] => 42
        )
```

i want to give a proper loop so that this problem skips and i do not need to change my template.

please help me out very much frusted tried all the stuffs.
 thankyou

Comment: check the array have value then only access its index value

Comment: yes thanks for that , but how to get that array in a loop so that it gets a continuity and shows the data which were available. i have tried the for each loop but no change , totally blank please help me out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

on your helper file.

```
function getRecord($params)
    {

        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        $query = "SELECT name,testimonial,regdate,id FROM #__testimonial WHERE published = '1' AND featured='1' ";
        $db->setQuery( $query);
        return $db->loadObjectList();

    }
```

In your module file `mod_testimonial.php` have something like

```
$data = helperClassname :: getRecord($param);
```

On your `default.php` have something like.

```
if(sizeof($data) > 0){

foreach($data as $key=>$value){

echo "<br/>Name".$value->name;
}

}
```

for more about module structure and calls check this [sample banner slide show module](http://www.walkswithme.net/joomla-banner-slideshow-module)

Hope its helps..